# Finding the next element value of a particular index in a Python list

Tags: python, list, nltk

I have a simple python program to find whether a sentence is a question or not.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

a = ["what are you doing","are you mad?","how sad"]
question =["what","why","how","are","am","should","do","can","have","could","when","whose","shall","is","would","may","whoever","does"];
word_list =["i","me","he","she","you","it","that","this","many","someone","everybody","her","they","them","his","we","am","is","are","was","were","should","did","would","does","do"];

def f(paragraph):
  sentences = paragraph.split(".")
  result = []

  for i in range(len(sentences)):

    token = word_tokenize(sentences[i])
    change_tense = [WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(word, 'v') for word in token]
    input_sentences = [item.lower() for item in change_tense]

    if input_sentences[-1]=='?':
        result.append("question")

    elif input_sentences[0] in question:
        find_question = [input_sentences.index(qestion) for qestion in input_sentences if qestion in question]
        if len(find_question) > 0:
            for a in find_question:
                if input_sentences[a + 1] in word_list:
                    result.append("question")
                else:
                    result.append("not a question")
    else:
        result.append("not a quetion")

return result
my_result = [f(paragraph) for paragraph in a]
print my_result
```

But it makes following error.

```
if input_sentences[a + 1] in word_list:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think problem cause in finding the next element value of the a. Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: just check if your "a+1" is not out of range in word list, a+1 < len(word_list)

Comment: It is available in the wordlist.

Comment: @DraykoonD `a+1` is not used to acceess `word_list` it's used to access `input_sentences`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `input_sentences.index(qestion)` can return the last index of `input_sentences`, which means that `a + 1` will be one larger than there are elements in `input_sentences`, this then causes the `IndexError` as you are trying to access an element of the list in `if input_sentences[a + 1] in word_list:` which does not exist.

You're logic for checking the "next element" therefore is incorrect, the last element in a list does not have a "next element". Looking at your wordlists a question like `What should I do` will fail as `do` will be picked up as a question word but there is nothing after it (assuming you strip punctuation). So you need to rethink the way in which you detect a question.

Comment: For that first I have checked input_sentences[0] in question.

Comment: oh I see, well then `What should I do` (without question mark) will still fail

Comment: yes if I say         elif (input_sentences[0] in question) and (input_sentences[1] in word_list):
            result.append("question") ?

Comment: you're focusing on the wrong thing! `input_sentences[a + 1]` will _always_ fail because `a` can point to the _last_ element in the list